# How to grep with nand (negative-AND) logical expression?

Tags: bash, grep

Two words/patterns are given: P1 and P2. How to implement a pipe filter, with `grep`, that suppress **every** line that ends with P1, **except** those that contain P2?

Edit: Examples, where P1 is "ok." and P2 is "Redefine" :

1. Should be passed

   ```
   X X not found.
   : X ;  Redefine X.  ok.
   ok. is not at end of line
   ?
   ```
2. Should be suppressed

   ```
   : X ;   ok.
   ```

Comment: Could you show a minimal testable example and add what you have tried so far?

Comment: And correct your english in the title

Comment: I updated with a couple of corner case examples according to my understanding; please review.

Comment: Hmmm, this is a job for `sed`, but I won't write code for you... Let us see what you already tried.

Comment: @tripleee , thanks for the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an Awk solution is acceptable, it is straightforward.

```
awk '/P2/ || !/P1$/' file
```

With `grep -P` you can say

```
grep -P 'P2|(?!P1$).{0,2}$' file
```

but this is harder to understand and not portable. Also note that the last quantifier needs to be updated to match the length of P1 (it should permit strings which are shorter than P1 if the line is too short to contain it in full).

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue. In the given e.g. the script is ```awk '/Redefine/ || !/ok[.]$/' ```

Comment: p.s. the grep doesn't work for some reason ```| grep -P 'Redefine|(?!ok[.]$).{0,2}$'```

Comment: Like it says in the answer, the quantifier needs to be `{0,3}` for a string of length 3.

Comment: the grep is "grep (GNU grep) 2.25" and it colorizes the output but everything is passed to the stdout

Answer (score 0):

See :

```
$ printf '%s\n' P1 P2 | grep -vP 'P(?=1)'
P2
```

Check [*look around regex*](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)

Answer (score 0):

Since "suppressing P1$ unless contains P2" is like "allowing P1 followed by something OR P2 followed by anything followed by P1 at the end":

```
$ (echo "asdfP2lkj P1" ; echo "asdfP3lkj P1" ; echo "P1 z") | \
    grep -P 'P1.+|P2.*P1$'

asdfP2lkj P1
P1 z
```

Comment: @Gilles: I like your reference to regex context. I wish I had a dollar for each grep I've done in my life, but I am a newbie to lookbehind/ahead/around. I appreciate the reference.

Comment: the rule is: if doesn't contain P1 then pass it , if contains P1 suppress it, if contains both P1 and P2 pass it .

Comment: @ivand58: where does your description of the rule address P1 at the end of the line? i.e. "suppress every line that ends with P1". I'm sure it's there, I just don't see it.